# Angular Dart errorRenderer pattern

Tags: angular, design-patterns, dart

How to use Error Renderer pattern from Angular Dart Components
Part of documentation indicates that it is possible.

https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular_components/0.8.0/base_material_input/materialInputErrorKey-constant.html

replaceErrors(Map overrides) → ErrorFn
Convience function for replacing multiple errors for Components using the errorRenderer pattern.

https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular_components/0.8.0/error_renderer/error_renderer-library.html

But it is not mentioned how to use it in practice.

Answer (score 0):

In view:

```
<material-input class="mat-input"
                floatingLabel
                label="Email"
                [errorRenderer]="replaceErrorMessage"
                trailingGlyph="mode_edit"
                type="email"
                [(ngModel)]="daneUzytkownika.daneIdentyfikacyjne.email">
</material-input>
```

In Controller

```
Map<String, String> customErrorRenderer = {

  'non-negative': 'nie niegatywna',
  'positive-number': 'pozytywna',
  'lower-bound-number': 'nizsza',
  'upper-bound-number': 'wyzsza',
  'check-integer': 'sprawdz integ',
  'material-input-number-error': 'errorrrr'

};

Map<String, dynamic> replaceErrorMessage(Map<String, dynamic> errors) {
  return customErrorRenderer;
}
```